# list.extend() cause the list to be char by char

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def commandTaskList(self, schid, targetMode, toID, fromID, params=""):
    import psutil
    msg = []
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            _p = str(p.as_dict(attrs=['name'])['name'])
            ts3lib.logMessage(_p, ts3defines.LogLevel.LogLevel_ERROR, "PyTSon", 0)
            if ".exe" in _p.lower(): msg.extend(_p)
        except psutil.Error: pass
    ts3lib.logMessage(str(msg), ts3defines.LogLevel.LogLevel_ERROR, "PyTSon", 0)
    msg = '\n'.join(sorted(msg))
    self.answerMessage(schid, targetMode, toID, fromID, msg)
```

This is my code and the first logMessage() shows:

```
1/28/2017 04:32:30  PyTSon  Error   RemindersServer.exe 
1/28/2017 04:32:30  PyTSon  Error   AutoHotkey.exe  
1/28/2017 04:32:30  PyTSon  Error   raptr_ep64.exe
```

The second one shows:

```
1/28/2017 04:32:30  PyTSon  Error   ['w', 'i', 'n', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'o', 'n', ...]
```

Comment: Yes. `extend` takes an iterable and `appends` the elements one-by-one to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `list.extend()` docstring:

> Docstring: L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements
>   from the iterable
>
> Type:      builtin_function_or_method

A string is considered as a sequence of characters and so it's an iterable.

`a.extend(b)` appends each element of `b` to `a`. Since in your case `b` is a string, each character of `b` is appended to `a` as a separate item. What you need is `a.append(b)` or `a.extend([b])`.

Comment: revert back if you don't like :)

Answer (score 1):

Use either, `[<your_list>].append("your string")` OR `[<you_list>].extend(["your string as a list of one element"])`

`str` is a sequence data type much like `list`. Consider this example:
`>>> [1, 2, 3].extend([4, 5, 6])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

The same rule applies to a `str` whose single characters serve as elements.